# Is there any way to lift content from IO to other container without run?

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats, io-monad, cats-effect

According to the cats official document: https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/typeclasses/liftio.html, if we want lift something from IO to other container, you should implement LiftIO trait, but the example explicitly run `unsafeRunXXX` method to fetch out the effect, I'm wondering is it the only way for the transformation?

Answer (score 5):

`IO` is suspending side-effects, and its type tells you what value you'll get if you run all computations (both side-effectful and pure), if there will be no error to throw in the end (they can be handled along the way).

As such, it is impossible to obtain the value without running the calculation. So, basically any useful translation from `IO[A]` to `F[A]`  would have to call some `.unsafeXXX` somewhere. The `unsafe` part doesn't mean, that you shouldn't use it - it means that **you need to know what you are doing** as the moment you run it, the result returned will be side-effecting, can fail and in general you give up on referential transparency.

That it why this it used in internally in `IOApp` (it uses it at the end of the world, where you want to have your results computed). You can also translate `IO` into another `F` without loosing referential transparency, if you know that this `F`:

- is lazy, just like IO,
- allows suspending side-effects, just like IO,
- handled errors, just like IO.

So basically, it is another implementation of the same concept - see: `SyncIO`, `Coeval`, `Task`, ZIO...

```scala
// example: Async can be used to translate IO into F
def IO2F[F[_]: Async]: IO ~> F = new (IO ~> F) {
  def apply[A](ioa: IO[A]): F[A] = Async[F].async(ioa.unsafeRunAsync)
}
```

You could also do things like `IO[A] => Either[Throwable, A]` or `IO[A] => Option[A]`, or `IO[A] => Future[A]` but then you have to remember that each time you run such evaluation, you are starting side effects immediately.

Long story short: of you want to translate `IO` into something else, you have to use some `.unsafeXXX` somewhere and this is not bad, `unsafe` is just a reminder that you have to be careful, that's it.